# Add/Remove JSON sub-tree in Python

Tags: python, json

Here is the empty JSON that I intend to use in my back end :

```
{
  "user": "",
  "mids": {
    "merchant_id": {
      "name": "",
      "cruise_credentials": {
        "APIkey": "",
        "APIidentifier": "",
        "OrgUnitId": ""
      },
      "SAWB": {
        "ProfileID": "",
        "AccesKey": "",
        "SecretKey": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Each user might have more than one Merchant ID. As such, I would need to be able to add another whole merchant_id subtree as followed :

```
{
  "user": "",
  "mids": {
    "merchant_id": {
      "name": "",
      "cruise_credentials": {
        "APIkey": "",
        "APIidentifier": "",
        "OrgUnitId": ""
      },
      "SAWB": {
        "ProfileID": "",
        "AccesKey": "",
        "SecretKey": ""
      }
    },
    "merchant_id2": {
      "name": "",
      "cruise_credentials": {
        "APIkey": "",
        "APIidentifier": "",
        "OrgUnitId": ""
      },
      "SAWB": {
        "ProfileID": "",
        "AccesKey": "",
        "SecretKey": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any easy way to achieve the addition/removal of a JSON in Python?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `"name":"IamNumber1":{` doesn't seem a valid

Comment: @Epsi95 I had a typo in the JSON it is now corrected. The idea would be to add the subtree merchant_id2 (and merchant_id3 ... 4... 5 ...).

Comment: If a key can have multiple values, you should probably use a list instead of changing the key name. `"merchant_id": [{"name": "one"}, {"name": "two"}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.update()`

```py
base = {
  "user": "",
  "mids": {
    "merchant_id": {
      "name": "",
      "cruise_credentials": {
        "APIkey": "",
        "APIidentifier": "",
        "OrgUnitId": ""
      },
      "SAWB": {
        "ProfileID": "",
        "AccesKey": "",
        "SecretKey": ""
      }
    }
  }
}

another_merchant = {"merchant_id2": {
      "name": "",
      "cruise_credentials": {
        "APIkey": "",
        "APIidentifier": "",
        "OrgUnitId": ""
      },
      "SAWB": {
        "ProfileID": "",
        "AccesKey": "",
        "SecretKey": ""
      }
    }
}
    
base["mids"].update(another_merchant)

print(base)
```

```
{
    "user": "",
    "mids":
    {
        "merchant_id":
        {
            "name": "",
            "cruise_credentials":
            {
                "APIkey": "",
                "APIidentifier": "",
                "OrgUnitId": ""
            },
            "SAWB":
            {
                "ProfileID": "",
                "AccesKey": "",
                "SecretKey": ""
            }
        },
        "merchant_id2":
        {
            "name": "",
            "cruise_credentials":
            {
                "APIkey": "",
                "APIidentifier": "",
                "OrgUnitId": ""
            },
            "SAWB":
            {
                "ProfileID": "",
                "AccesKey": "",
                "SecretKey": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help.

There is 2 solutions depending on how we would handle this.

Using a LIST of merchant_id would allow for simple addition of a new dictionary NAME after the first NAME dictionary.

```
{
  "user": "",
  "merchant_id": [
      {
      "name": "",
      "cruise_credentials": {
        "APIkey": "",
        "APIidentifier": "",
        "OrgUnitId": ""
      },
      "SAWB": {
        "ProfileID": "",
        "AccesKey": "",
        "SecretKey": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "",
      "cruise_credentials": {
        "APIkey": "",
        "APIidentifier": "",
        "OrgUnitId": ""
      },
      "SAWB": {
        "ProfileID": "",
        "AccesKey": "",
        "SecretKey": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Or we can use the .update() function. However, this would force us to change the field "merchant_name" ourself to merchant _name2 and would require additional logic.